# FATAL: password authentication failed for user that I just created, with a correct password.I

Tags: postgresql, python, django

I installed `postgres` with `Django` [following this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Here I created a database and a user in the `postgres` command line :

```
CREATE DATABASE myProject;
CREATE USER myUser WITH PASSWORD '1234';
```

When I try to connect to this database, either through `Django` or directly via `pscopg2` I get the wrong password error.

```
#connect through python
import psycopg2
psycopg2.connect("dbname=myProject user=myUser host=localhost password=1234 port=5432")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myUser"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myUser"
```

In this question I've replaced my actual project names, user name and password. But I've double, triple checked and the names/passwords I'm writing down are all correct.

How am I getting a bad password request? How can I fix this?

**EDIT**: The contents of my `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Check your `pg_hba.conf` file.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for the tip. What should I check it for specifically? I'm unfamiliar with using postgres beyond what that guide thought me

Comment: @MichaelHampton.  I've added my pg_hba.conf file to my original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody finding this question, let it be noted that apparently the database name and the username are *always* in lowercase, even if you create them with capitals.

As such, creating a database and user like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE myProject;
CREATE USER myUser WITH PASSWORD '1234';
```

Means the exact same as doing this:

```
CREATE DATABASE myproject;
CREATE USER myuser WITH PASSWORD '1234';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for creating the user for Postgres

`postgres=# create user username with encrypted password 'password';`

Add permissions

`postgres=# grant all on database db_name to username;`

other useful commands might help

`sudo -u postgres psql`

`\du+ #list of user`

`\l+ # list of DB`

Credits to
[this artical](http://www.dark-hamster.com/application/how-to-solve-error-message-got-an-error-checking-a-consistent-migration-history-performed-for-database-connection-default-in-running-django-application/)